# Jenkins Project Not Running Correctly When Slave is Connected via Windows Service?

Tags: jenkins, windows-services

I have a Jenkins project that runs automated tests on a slave machine. However, when I set the connection to the slave node up as a Windows Service, and run the project on that connection, the build itself will "succeed" (sometimes) but my tests will not run correctly. When the build does succeed, the console output looks like everything went fine; I know it isn't how it should be though, because the Selenium web browser never runs on the slave machine during the execution when it's done through the Service connection. At one point I thought it might be because installing the slave-agent as a Service puts all of the associated files in the same directory that the slave node is based in by default, but when I changed the path to the executable for the Service and moved all of the files, it would still connect, and the project still wouldn't run as it should.

As soon as I delete the Service, and launch a connection manually from my slave machine, everything goes through as expected.

Does anyone know why this might be happening? Or, if not, do you know of an alternative to connecting at startup? Thanks in advance for your advice/ideas.

Comment: Have you set permissions properly.  The slave task runs with the local account which may not have access to the paths or tools you are trying to use.  As a service in the background, you may also need to allow the service to interact with the desktop.

Comment: I'm not sure-- I'll have to look more into that. Thank you.

Comment: @StevenScott, do you know if this situation (build succeeding, reports being generated about test results) means the tests are running headlessly? The console output looks the same whether I run it as a service or not; the only difference is that I don't actually SEE Selenium running on the slave. If they are headless, that may actually be a good thing, but I need to figure out if this is the case or if Jenkins is showing me what LOOKS like a successful headless run.

Comment: The service will not show up on the computer running the tests, unless you enable the check box to allow the service to interact with the desktop.

Comment: Okay-- Thank you, @StevenScott.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just moving my comment to an answer so you can accept it as you indicated this resolved the problem, and should make it easier for others to follow.

Have you set permissions properly? The slave task runs with the local account which may not have access to the paths or tools you are trying to use. As a service in the background, you may also need to allow the service to interact with the desktop.

The service will not show up on the computer running the tests, unless you enable the check box to allow the service to interact with the desktop:

[image: interact with the desktop]

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who may be having this problem, I wanted to post the solution I ended up using (I'm not accepting it as the answer to this particular question because it's a work-around; however, @StevenScott has the answer to making this work as a Service in the comment he posted, above.)

I nixed the Service I created and made a Scheduled Task that utilized a batch script to connect the JNLP file instead.There is a command on the slave node's page in Jenkins that has a command line option, but this did not work for me in the batch file; rather, I simply wrote it to cd to a directory that already contained a copy of the slave-agent.jnlp and just ran it from there: [slave agent batch script screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YW9Iy.png)

For this to work, you will need to disable the pop-up that appears when you run the slave-agent (the one that asks if you want to run the program).

The settings for the task should include the following:

- General Settings: "Run only when user is logged on"
- Triggers: "At log on" (specify your user account)
- Actions: "Start a program" (specify the location of your batch script)